# Using Angular Template with JHipster

Tags: jhipster

I have done a few tutorials of JHipster and was impressed with the productivity. But what is still bugging me is that usually we get a Angular Template which we should use to develop the application. How can I integrate that to my JHipster application?

I read about creating own modules, but is that the way to go? What are the advantages of such approach over replacing the `/layout` stuff?